# Is what I am trying to do with sql even possible?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a specific information in a table I am looking for, this query will show it:

```
SELECT StringValue FROM ClientSettings
WHERE Setting like 'CompanyDomain'
OR Setting like 'CompanyActivityEmail'
OR Setting like 'CompanySupportPhone'
OR Setting like 'CompanyName'
```

It returns the following date:

```
StringValue
MyCompanyName
MyCompanyName@email.com
www.mycompanydomain.com
801-555-1212
```

I am trying to now set these up to variables without having to make 4 separate select statements.

Here is what I have, but it is not working as I want it to:

```
DECLARE @CompanyName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CompanyDomain VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @CompanyName = StringValue, @CompanyDomain = StringValue FROM ClientSettings
WHERE Setting like 'CompanyName'
OR Setting like 'CompanyDomain'

SELECT @CompanyName
SELECT @CompanyDomain
```

I am curious if what I am even trying is possible?

Comment: Just a note: If you're doing a `LIKE 'SomeText'` without any wildcards, you might as well do =. Also, if you're doing `Setting = 'CompanyName' OR Setting = 'ComanyDomain'` you can do that cleaner without an `OR` by writing `Setting IN ('CompanyName', 'CompanyDomain')`

Comment: I started out with =, and had an error, switched it to like with %'s, figure out my error, removed the %'s but never switched it back to =.  You are right on all accounts tho, thank you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you should only assign one value for each row, but not overwrite the other variables at the same time.  A `CASE` statement should let you do this:

```
DECLARE @CompanyName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CompanyDomain VARCHAR(100)

SELECT 
    @CompanyName = CASE WHEN Setting = 'CompanyName' 
        THEN StringValue ELSE @CompanyName END, 
    @CompanyDomain = CASE WHEN Setting = 'CompanyDomain' 
        THEN StringValue ELSE @CompanyDomain END
FROM ClientSettings
WHERE Setting like 'CompanyName'
OR Setting like 'CompanyDomain'

SELECT @CompanyName
SELECT @CompanyDomain
```

Comment: You are the man, exactly what I was looking for.  I can't seem to ever (at) your name tho.  Thank you again!

Comment: @JamesWilson You're welcome... I think you just have to leave out the space... `@MichaelFredrickson`.

Comment: I've tried that.  Normally when I do `@M` it pops up a list to verify it is you.  But nothing ever pops up and even when I do `@MichaelFredrickson` @MichaelFredrickson it vanishes when I submit the post.  Oh well tho, at least it still alerts you of a comment. :)

Comment: +1 nice Case statement btw. The case version I was working on was not  as nice. It required `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`

Answer (score 4):

You can use PIVOT to do this, but its a little hacky since it requires the use of an aggregate to work

```
DECLARE @CompanyName VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @CompanyDomain VARCHAR(100) 

SELECT @CompanyName = [CompanyName], 
       @CompanyDomain = [CompanyDomain] 
FROM   (SELECT setting, 
               stringvalue 
        FROM   clientsettings 
        WHERE  setting LIKE 'CompanyName' 
                OR setting LIKE 'CompanyDomain') AS sourcetable PIVOT ( MAX( 
       stringvalue 
       ) FOR setting IN ([CompanyName], [CompanyDomain]) ) AS pivottable

SELECT @CompanyName, 
       @CompanyDomain
```

[Working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f82af/1)

Comment: I'm sure this would have worked, but the compatibility level of the database is too low.  I've never even heard of some of the things like PIVOT.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @James you should go with Michael's version (since its not as hacky) but you should give PIVOT a try anyway. Compatibility levels don't block new syntax.

Comment: @ConradFrix Could you change that phone number to 801-555-1212 I don't want to receive personal calls from strangers lol, silly me forgot to leave it out.  I tried it on your working demo, but the new syntax still gave me compatibility issues on my live machine.

Comment: @James Took care of the sqlfiddle for you but that's odd about the pivot. I'm curious what version of SQL are using and what's the compatiblity level set to?

Comment: @JamesWilson never mind I was wrong I hadn't tested the Compatibility mode correctly

Comment: @ConradFrix well it was still a pretty cool way to do it. :).  The version is 10.50.1617.0 (SQL Server 2008 R2) and the compatibility level is 80.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT setting, StringValue 
FROM ClientSettings
WHERE Setting in ('CompanyDomain'
                  ,'CompanyActivityEmail'
                  ,'CompanySupportPhone'
                  ,'CompanyName')
```

then loop on the results and assign your variables.

Comment: This way would have worked, was just trying to handle everything in SQL, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate approach, you could make a table called, say `company_settings` with a single column of `Setting` that has the values `'CompanyDomain'`,`'CompanyActivityEmail'`,etc.

Then you can do:

```
SELECT StringValue FROM ClientSettings
WHERE Setting is in (select Setting from company_settings);
```

or simply:

```
SELECT StringValue 
FROM ClientSettings a
JOIN company_settings b
ON (a.Setting=b.Setting);
```